# How can I force ElementTree to write to disk every change?

Tags: python, elementtree

I have to deal with a huge XML file I create from a big database.

From the database structure I generate an XML tree, but it ends up eating all my memory (over 10gb now), so the process will never end since the system can't process any new query.

I think that the solution is to avoid saving all the XML structure into memory, and dump it directly into the disk whenever I add something new.

Is that something I can actually do? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how your code works, but it's definitely something that could be done. Depending on how it's structured, you could create a timestamp and compare the incoming data to the old data, or you could scan the file for whether the current XML has already been added. After that (assuming its new code) you could do something like the following:

```
path = "path/"
name = "fileName"

xmlRoot = Element("root")#create a root element for the xml structure
xmlSub = SubElement(xmlRoot,"sub")
subName = SubElement(xmlCard,"name")
subName.text = "element text"

saveName = path + name + ".xml" #constructs location of xml file (path/fileName.xml)
tree = ElementTree(xmlRoot) #compiles the tree
tree.append(saveName) #appends to specified file
```

This would output the following in a document in the folder "path" under the name "fileName.xml"

```
<root>
    <sub>
        <name>element text</name>
    </sub>
</root>
```

If you wanted to scan an XML document for an object, do the following:

```
xml = parse("path/fileName.xml")
nameList = xml.findall("sub/name") #find all objects in <name> brackets
for i in nameList:
    i.text #convert item in the list to a readable string
    #do comparison here
```

I hope this helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with another solution (no xml at all!), but your answer is great.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! eTree can be annoying sometimes to work with. Happy coding!